# How to keep QWidgets in QTreeWidget hidden during resize?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I have a simple UI with QWidgets within a QTreeWidget.
Some of them need to be hidden.
Every time the application is resized, all QWidgets become visible.
Below is a minimal example to demonstrate the issue.
How can I make sure the QWidgets stay hidden until `setVisible(True)` is called explicitly?
pyqt version is 5.12.3

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTreeWidgetItem, QTreeWidget, QCheckBox, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
import sys

class Foo(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):   
        super().__init__() 
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        tree = QTreeWidget()
        
        item = QTreeWidgetItem()
        tree.addTopLevelItem(item)
        self.checkBox = QCheckBox()
        tree.setItemWidget(item,0,self.checkBox)        
        
        button = QPushButton('Hide Checkbox')
        button.clicked.connect(self.hideCheckbox)
        
        lay.addWidget(tree)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(button)
    
    def hideCheckbox(self):
        self.checkBox.setVisible(False)  # is reset on resize
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Have you considered adding the checkbox only when you actually need it? Also, is there a reason for using a checkbox instead of using [`setCheckState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#setCheckState)?

Comment: See [QTBUG-13522](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13522) (and various duplicates). It seems doubtful that this will ever be fixed, so you will have to remove/reset instead of hide/show.

Comment: @musicamante I added QWidgets as I also needed access to other fields. The issue is not specific for QCheckBox but happens with other QWidgets as well.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for pointing me to the bug. I'm using `removeItemWidget` now and recreate the Widgets later. This makes the code a bit more messy but it works.

Comment: @dukeeloo I know that it's not specific to QCheckBox, but it's usually better (and simpler) to use the existing features whenever possible. As long as you're adding *only* a QCheckBox, you should prefer the check state role that the model already provides. Clearly, if you also want to add a container with *more* widgets on the same item, the problem is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that this is caused by a call to the *private* `updateEditorGeometries()` function of item views, which automatically shows index widgets whenever the view updates the geometry of its contents, there's no direct control over that.

There are two possible workarounds, though.

### Add the item widget to a container

In this case, the item widget is a basic QWidget that acts as a container for the *actual* widget. Since the `show()` will only be called on the item widget, explicitly hiding the child widgets will avoid the problem:

```py
    self.checkBox = QCheckBox()
    container = QWidget()
    containerLayout = QHBoxLayout(container)
    containerLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    containerLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
    tree.setItemWidget(item, 0, container)
```

Note that it's important to set the contents margins to 0 (otherwise the default Qt layout margins would be added).

### Override `updateGeometries()` in a QTreeWidget subclass

[`updateGeometries()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#updateGeometries) is called by item views whenever they are resized or the contents of the viewport require internal changes (columns/rows are resized, the model has changed, etc).

You could create a subclass of QTreeWidget, keep an internal list of widgets set for items, and then keep track of the hidden ones *before* calling the base implementation:

```
class TreeWidget(QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.itemWidgets = set()

    def setItemWidget(self, item, column, widget):
        self.itemWidgets.add(widget)
        widget.destroyed.connect(lambda: self.itemWidgets.discard(widget))
        super().setItemWidget(item, column, widget)

    def updateGeometries(self):
        hidden = [w for w in self.itemWidgets if w.isHidden()]
        super().updateGeometries()
        for widget in hidden:
            widget.setVisible(False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. I'm using the first option and it works very well.